# Java stream create object and compare

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty new to Java streams. I've to split a string returned by filter in stream, create a new object with the strings in the split and compare each object with a predefined object. Stream looks like this (I know this is incorrect, just a representation of what I am trying to do):

```
xmlstream.stream()
         .filter(xml->xml.getName()) //returns a string
         .map(returnedString -> split("__"))
         .map(eachStringInList -> new TestObj(returnedStr[0], returnedStr[1]))
         .map(eachTestObj -> eachTestObj.compareTo(givenObj))
         .max(Comparing.compare(returnedObj :: aProperty))
```

How do I achieve this? Basically map each string in list to create an object, compare that to a fix object and return max based on one of the properties.
Thanks.

Comment: If you need to find max between objects equal to `givenObj` than streams have `filter` functionality `filter(obj -> obj.equals(givenObj))`.
After that stream will contain only objects that are equal to `givenObj`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` like so:

```
TestObj predefined = ...

TestObj max = 
       xmlstream.stream()
                .map(xml -> xml.getName()) //returns a string
                .map(s -> s.split("__"))
                .map(a -> new TestObj(a[0], a[1]))
                .reduce(predifined, (e, a) -> 
                      e.aProperty().compareTo(a.aProperty()) >= 0 ? e : a);
```

A more efficient version of the above would be:

```
TestObj predefined = ...
TestObj max =
        xmlstream.stream()
                 .map(xml -> xml.getName()) //returns a string
                 .map(s -> s.split("__"))
                 .map(a -> new TestObj(a[0], a[1]))
                 .filter(e -> e.aProperty().compareTo(predefined.aProperty()) > 0)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(predefined);
```

**Update:**

if you want to retrieve the max object by a given property from all the `TestObj` objects less than the predefined `TestObj`, then you can proceed as follows:

```
TestObj predefined = ...
Optional<TestObj> max =
             xmlstream.stream()
                      .map(xml -> xml.getName()) 
                      .map(s -> s.split("_"))
                      .map(a -> new TestObj(a[0], a[1]))
                      .filter(e -> e.aProperty().compareTo(predefined.aProperty()) < 0)
                      .max(Comparator.comparing(TestObj::aProperty));
```

`max` returns an `Optional<T>`; if you're unfamiliar with it then consult the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to familiarise you're with the different ways to unwrap an `Optional<T>` object.

Comment: Won't `findFirst` return the first object less than predefinedObject? I want the max of all the matches. The incoming stream is not sorted. Nevertheless, this looks like the correct solution, if I use max.

Comment: No, the `findFirst` will get the first object where the `aProperty()` is greater than `predefined.aProperty()` otherwise we return `predefined`, that's what the second code snippet does. what do you mean _I want the max of all the matches_?

Comment: So, if I find 3 objects less than the predefined object, I want to find the object that is greatest among all the matches. Example: compare returns following objects less than predefined: a_1, a_2, a_3. I need a_3. Findfirst may return a_1, correct?

Comment: @Maxsteel if I am not mistaken, you want the max object of all the objects less than the predefined object?

Comment: Thanks for putting the efforts to answer this accurately and clearly. Much appreciated! :)